# convert String publickey to RSA publickey

Tags: java, android, rsa

I'm trying to convert string public key to publickey with modulus and exponent.
but how come it doesnt works?

this is my code

```
     public void toPubKey(String filename,String sms) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidKeySpecException, IOException{
    byte[]keyBytes=sms.getBytes();
    byte[]decode = Base64.encode(keyBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    X509EncodedKeySpec x509KeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(decode);
    PublicKey pubKey2 = (PublicKey)fact.generatePublic(x509KeySpec);
    saveToFile(filename,pubKey2);
```

any problem with my code?

Comment: see if that helps: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/cryptography/rsa_encryption.shtml

Comment: no..:( i dun think so :(

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you meant your code to be:

```
byte[]decode = Base64.decode(keyBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Change `encode` to `decode`.